# org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus link is grayed out

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created my own eclipse view and is trying to add a link in a popup menu. I am able to add the link but it's grayed out. I wonder how I can activate the link. I just want to be able to click on the link and trigger run().  DeleteAction is the class i want to trigger. SegmentReferencesView is the view I created. Would be very thankful for help.

This is from the plugin.xml:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">    
  <viewerContribution     
        id="se.test.views.categories.segmentreferences.ui.views"
        targetID="se.test.views.categories.segmentreferences.ui.views.SegmentReferencesView">
     <action
           class="se.test.views.categories.segmentreferences.ui.views.DeleteAction"
           enablesFor="1"
           icon="icons/Delete.gif"
           id="se.test.views.categories.segmentreferences.ui.views.DeleteReferenceAction"
           label="Do action"
           menubarPath="additions-ext"> 
     </action>
  </viewerContribution>
```

This is the Java class:

```java
public class DeleteAction implements IViewActionDelegate {

    @Override
    public void init(org.eclipse.ui.IViewPart view) {
        super.init(view);       
    };

    @Override
    public void run(IAction action) {       
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got exactly one item selected in the view? Have you defined a 'selection provider' for the view?

Comment: Yes I have one item selected when i right click on it. I have not defined a selection provider. Do you know how to do this?

(Thank  you for cleaning up my code. First time on Stackowerflow.)

Comment: What is in your view? Are you using something like TreeViewer or TableViewer?

Comment: I'm using a TableViewer. When i right click on an item in the view a popup list comes up. I want to add the link to the list and make it clickable. I've managed to add the link, but I can't click on it. I wonder if I can do something in the init() method to activate the link?

Answer (score 0):

Your view must set the view site 'Selection Provider'. This is used by the menu system to find out what is selected. If you are using a `TableViewer` or `TreeViewer` you can just do:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
```

in the view code immediately after you have created `viewer` (which should be the `TableViewer` or `TreeViewer`).

Comment: Where do I get the viewer from?

Comment: You told me you were using `TableViewer` - that is what you use.

Comment: The code I posted is the code I have plus the code for the SegmentReferencesView and an Activator class that extends AbstractUIPlugin. Do you think I could get the TableViewer from the init() method somehow?

Comment: This code goes in `SegmentReferencesView` where you create the table.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by extending org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler in the DeleteAction class.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the link to work by extending org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler in the DeleteAction class. I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it's working for now.

```
public class DeleteAction extends AbstractHandler implements IViewActionDelegate {

    @Override
    public void init(org.eclipse.ui.IViewPart view) {
    // Not used
    }

    @Override
    public void run(IAction action) {       
       System.out.println("run"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
       // Not used
    }

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
       return null;
    }
```

}